# Select statement having multiple conditions over multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

A part of my table is as follows,

```
Key|Value
---------
 A | V1
 B | V2
 C | V3
```

I know the following query would definitely return no result, but then what is the correct query of achieving a positive result, i.e. '1'.

I mean what query should I apply that checks that A has a value as V1 and B has a value as V2 and then returns me '1'. 
The new query should fail to return anything if either A or B has different results.

Assume the table as a Map of key/value pairs. Only difference here is it's not a Java map but a table in Oracle Db. So, how to achieve a result that satisfies both the key/value pairs.

```
select 1 from myTable 
where (key = 'A' and value = 'V1') 
  AND (key = 'B' and value = 'V2');
```

Let me know if the design of the table itself needs some change.

Comment: What's a positive result? A result with rows? Then, just remove the complete `WHERE` clause ;-)

Comment: I have rephrased my question. Positive means that it returns the result as '1' and not no-result.

Comment: What do you want to select? The current condition wants a single row where the key is both "A" and "B".

Comment: I want to get the result as 1 so that I can put it in a Cursor. So, when the cursor is opened I can validate accordingly.

Comment: I know that's why I ask what is the better way to achieve this. Maybe some different sql query or maybe the table itself needs a design change.

Comment: When should 1 be "returned" and when should it not? Your query, as you state, never returns anything. On what condition should it return something?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing some sleep but I still can't understand the criteria to filter out rows... if that's the question. If all you need is a query that always returns `1`, all you need is `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL`.

Comment: '1' should be returned when A has a value as V1 and B has a value as V2. '1' should not be returned when A or B has some different values.

Comment: I think the OP wants the query to return 1, only when both rows A V1 and B V2 are present in the table.

Comment: @Ramblin'Man Yes you are absolutely correct. Also if you think my table has some design issues, then let me know. But I want to have query that can satisfy both the key value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only want to check if there are rows that fulfill certain conditions you can use following construct

```
select count(*) from dual
where exists (
               select 1  
               from myTable 
               where (key = 'A' and value = 'V1')                       
              )
 AND exists (
               select 1  
               from myTable 
               where (key = 'B' and value = 'V2')                       
              );
```

Comment: This works even if 'B' has a value other than 'V2'. If you see my question I have put an AND in between, which means I'm looking for a solution that matches both keys having expected values.

Comment: @Arham no, with that code you are looking for a single key that has a value of "A" and has a value of "B", like if you are looking for a man that is both male and female.

Comment: so you mean the table itself needs some design change? Can you suggest some design?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want.

```
select 1 from dual
 where exists(
              select 1
                from mytable
               where key = 'A' and value = 'V1')
   and exists(
              select 1
                from mytable
               where key = 'B' and value = 'V2')
```

Comment: Thanks Ramblin. It worked and +1 for your answer. But @schurik replied the same answer before you, so will mark his answer correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using my powers of psychic debugging:

You want to have a value of 1 if:

1. There is a row with Key="A" and value="V1" AND
2. There is another row with Key="B" and value="V2"

To get a row like the first you need:

```
select 1 from myTable where key = 'A' and value = 'V1'
```

To get a row like the second you need

```
select 1 from myTable where key = 'B' and value = 'V2'
```

Now you need to make sure that both those rows exist.

It's not a simple as it sounds, since SQL checks all `where` conditions on a single row, so a statement like:

```
select 1 from myTable where key = 'A' and key = 'B'
```

is nonsensical, because it requires the key column to have two distinct values simultaneously.

One (inefficient) solution is to join the table to itself

```
select 1 
from mytable t1
  cross join mytable t2
where t1.Key = 'A' and t1.Value='V1'
  and t2.Key = 'B' and t2.Value='V2'
```

This will make a Cartesian product of the tables, joining each row with each other row. It will generate

```
t1.Key|t1.Value|t2.Key|t2.Value
-------------------------------
 A    | V1     |  A    |  V1
 B    | V2     |  A    |  V1
 C    | V3     |  A    |  V1
 A    | V1     |  B    |  V2   <-- the row you need
 B    | V2     |  B    |  V2   
 C    | V3     |  B    |  V2   
 A    | V1     |  C    |  V3   
 B    | V2     |  C    |  V3   
 C    | V3     |  C    |  V3
```

and will enable you to check two rows of the original table at the same time.

Note that this will generate a table of count^2 rows, so ***DO NOT USE IT*** if the table has more than a few rows, or if you need to check more than two rows simultaneously.